# Firestore security rule get() not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In firestore I want a user to only access a document if the user is in the `teamid` mentioned in the document. Now I have a different collection called `teams` where I have users mapped as `{ user_id = true }`. So I have the following in the Firestore rules

```
return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(resource.data.teamid)).data.approvedMembers[request.auth.uid] == true;
```

Now this rule does not work and fails any request made to the database by the frontend. But when I replace `$(resource.data.teamid)` with my actual `teamid` value as follows,

```
return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/234234jk2jk34j23).data.approvedMembers[request.auth.uid] == true;
```

... it works as expected.

Now my question is am I using `resource` in a wrong way or is `resource` not supported in `get()` or `exists()` queries in Firestore rules?

**Edit**
Complete rules as follows

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isTeamMember() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(resource.data.teamid)).data.approvedMembers[request.auth.uid] == true;
        // return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(resource.data.teamid));
    }

    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if isTeamMember();
    }
  }
}
```

If you notice the commented out rule, `exists()` does not work in this case either.

Comment: Are you performing a query against multiple docs in a collection, or fetching a single document?

Comment: Hey @ToddKerpelman. Yes I am querying multiple documents.

Comment: Can you show more of your rules, including the `match` and `allow get` statements where this applies?

Comment: @SamStern I have added complete rules in the question

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reaching out on Twitter.  Following our chat, here is the conclusion:

### Querying documents using your security rule

You cannot use a security rule as a filter.  To get this to work, you must also add `.where('teamid', '==', yourTeamId)`

*You have confirmed that this works for you, but you don't always want to restrict on one teamid*

### Using custom claims

You can set up custom claims in your authentication tokens.  Here is an example of how to set these and them use them in your rules

#### Setting custom claim

You will need to use the Admin SDK for this.

```
auth = firebase.auth();

const userId = 'exampleUserId';
const customClaims = {teams: {myTeam1: true, myTeam2: true}};

return auth.setCustomUserClaims(userId, customClaims)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Custom claim created');
    return auth.getUser(userId);
  })
  .then(userRecord => {
    console.log(`name: ${userRecord.displayName}`);
    console.log(`emailVerified: ${userRecord.emailVerified}`);
    console.log(`email: ${userRecord.email}`);
    console.log(`emailVerified: ${userRecord.emailVerified}`);
    console.log(`phoneNumber: ${userRecord.phoneNumber}`);
    console.log(`photoURL: ${userRecord.photoURL}`);
    console.log(`disabled: ${userRecord.disabled}`);
    console.log(`customClaims: ${JSON.stringify(userRecord.customClaims)}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

#### Apply security rule

```
allow read, write: if request.auth.token.teams.$(resource.data.teamId) == true;
```

I'm still not 100% certain that this will not also require you to filter by the `teamid`. Please test it and feed back.

Answer (score 1):

You have this `match`:

```
match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if isTeamMember();
}
```

That will match any document in the database.  That means when you call `isTeamMember()` it's not guaranteed that `resource` represents a `team` document.  If you have any subcollections on `teams` and write to those then `resource` will be the subcollection document.

Comment: `isTeamMember()` will run for every document. But that is the intended behaviour. It only needs to access `teamid` in the requested resource. And right now we have made a conscious decision to include `teamid` in every document of every collection and subcollection Every document in every collection has `teamid`. Shouldnt the query work then?